# Asus laptop shuts off randomly

Tags: laptop, battery, shutdown

I Have X541U Asus laptop with Windows 10 and it is about a year old. Initially the laptop was fine but recently it has started randomly shutting down without warning when not plugged in.

I am not sure if it's the battery issue because if it were then It wouldn't work when not plugged in. In my case after plugging out I can use it for about 20 mins but then shuts off. Then I turn it on again and sometimes it survives 100% battery discharge but sometimes it doesn't go more than even booting. I have tried everything but nothing's working. Any suggestions?

Comment: Just to be sure: it never randomly shuts down when plugged in? IN which case I am tempted to blame battery and or contacts to the battery.

Comment: I was about to write about overheating issues. Pushing temps too much will make your compuer to drain the battery faster.

Answer (score 0):

According to other experiences, you can try this too:

- Clean your RAM contacts (air pressure or contact-cleaner)
- Update the antivirus and perform a scan
- Replace the battery
- It may be hardware failure, that detect overheating condition when it is not

Comment: While these are good suggestions. 3 of them don't make any sense if this problem does not occur when on ac power.